# Formatting Float Value to specific Format - Java vs C# Number Formatting

Tags: java, c#, formatting, number-formatting

I need to convert Byte to KB.So i divide the value by `1024`
I need to display the value in this format specified originally in Java Number formatting  `###,###,###,##0.00 KB`

This code

```
 string format="###,###,###,##0.00 KB";
 return String.Format(format, x);
```

produces the following output
***###,###,###,##0.00 KB***

This formatting string is specified in the Java counterpart,wont the same approach work in C#?
Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Format` and `IFormattable.ToString` (the formatting you need here) are different, yet related things.

`String.Format` requires some format string with placeholders and the substituted values can also have formatting if they implement the `IFormattable` interface.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} KB", 42.ToString("###,###,###,##0.00")));
```

The formatting of 42 can be inlined:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:###,###,###,##0.00} KB", 42));
```

Which can be simplified further by interpoation:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{42:###,###,###,##0.00} KB"));
```

Of course, `42` can be a variable in the interpolation (`$"{numValue:###,###,###,##0.00} KB}"`). However, the format string cannot be a variable, so this will not work:

```
string format = "{x} KB";
Console.WriteLine($format); // does not compile, use String.Format in this case
```

**Remark:**

`Console.WriteLine` also supports formatting so the examples above could have been written like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:###,###,###,##0.00} KB", 42);
```

I used explicit `String.Format` just to avoid confusion.

---

### Update

If the size formatting comes from an external source you cannot inline it into the format string but this is not a problem. So if you have

```
string fileSizeFormat = "###,###,###,##0.00 KB";
```

You can still use `myFloatWithFileSize.ToString(fileSizeFormat)`. In this case `String.Format` is needed only if you want to embed this into a nice sentence or something:

```
return String.Format("The size of the file: {0}", fileSize.ToString(fileSizeFormat));
```

or with interpolation:

```
return $"The size of the file: {fileSize.ToString(fileSizeFormat)}";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) .. This value `###,###,###,##0.00 KB` will be provided by the server and will be stored in a string.How can i properly set the formatting in this case? Also the formatting is subjected to be changed by the server.Basically this should support normal Java Number formatting